# Can't build debug android bundle and apk

Tags: react-native

I set up react native cli following the Facebook Opensource guide and now want to build a debug apk, release apk and android bundle. For this, I followed the tutorial at https://www.instamobile.io/android-development/generate-react-native-release-build-android/.

When I give the command for react-native bundle..., it works successfully and creates an "index.android.bundle" file in android/app/src/main/assets. When I do "gradlew assembleRelease" or "gradlew assembleDebug" in android folder, I get an error "could not find method android()". Note when the tutorial says go to android/app/build.gradle and edit the android {...} block, it does not exist in my file. I had to create one. I removed android {...} and just left signingConfigs bit, but then get "could not find method signingConfigs".

I spoke to a friend and he said he gets a bundle called "index.aab", so I changed the command and I got a .aab file too. Then I downloaded bundletools and tried to make an apk with that, but it said "something is wrong with index.aab".

Please help! I'm stuck for six months now! I wish I could contact someone from the react-native team directly and they could help, but couldn't find their contact either!

(I'm a blind developer and android studios is suuuuuuuperrrr slow with my screenreader)

Comment: If your build.gradle was missing the android block, it looks like your project is wasn't properly configured by the cli. I had something similar happening to me. You can try creating a new project, trying to create the apk for that project, but with the boilerplate code and config, and if that works, start migrating your code to the new project

Comment: you have to make sur that signingConfigs is a child of the android element, can you share with us your build.gradle file (or android {} part) and also your RN version?

Comment: So I have rn 0.62, sdk 28 and something happened. I deleted everything in users/Natsu/.gradle folder, deleted everything in android/app/src/main/res/raw and then I got a build by `gradlew assembleRelease`. But it didn't ask for my key password or anything. But the size of a Hello World apk was 57MB, so I got NDK (side by side) and CMake, and now the size is 44MB. By .aab files, I can shrink it to I think 12-13 MBs. But the point is, it's still too big, and it's not asking for my keystore. Thanks guys for helping, I think we'll get it done soon